# Select form the attribute table in with OGR

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr, query

I want to select the (Sumava) from the attribute table and then make a shapefile. My problem is I don't know which function should I use to select this area.

If any one can help me?

```
import ogr
import os
direction_parks = 'ArcCR500_v32/ChranenaUzemi.shp'
direction_result = 'ArcCR500_v32/result.shp'

open_parks = ogr.Open(direction_parks)
layer_park = open_parks.GetLayer(0)

layer_park.SetAttributeFilter("???????")

number_park = layer_park.GetFeatureCount()


driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI shapefile")

if os.path.exists(direction_result):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(direction_result)

dataset = driver.CreateDataSource(direction_result)

new_layer = dataset.CreateLayer(direction_result, geom_type= ogr.wkbPolygon)

number = 0
for j in range(0, number_park):
    h = layer_park.GetNextFeature()
    h_geometry = h.GetGeometryRef()

    new_layer.CreateFeature(h)

dataset.Destroy()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
layer_park.SetAttributeFilter("NAZEV_ASCI = 'Sumava'")
```

You can also do this with a pure SQL statement:

```
open_parks.ExecuteSQL("SELECT ∗ FROM layer_name WHERE NAZEV_ASCI = ’Sumava’ ")
```

Comment: thanks it works, and how can i add data from another attribute table to the new shape file attribute table

Comment: Just copy this layer. You've already got filter on it, so: `filter= driver.CreateDataSource ( " filter.shp ")` and next `filter_layer = filter.CopyLayer( layer_park, ’ filter’)`

Comment: ok,but i don't have a file like filter.shp i have a .dbf file , and i want to get the data just for my selected area(Sumava)

Comment: can i ask what do you mean by ’ filter’ what should i insert insert of that

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook:Filter by attribute](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/layers.html)

```
layer_parks.SetAttributeFilter("NAZEV_ASCI= 'Sumava'")
```

But it is easier with [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html), another ogr Python wrapper where everything is Python dictionaries.

```
with fiona.open("ChranenaUzemi.shp") as input:
    with fiona.open('result.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', input.schema.copy(), crs=input.ces as output:
         for feature in input:
            if feature['properties']['NAZEV_ASCI'] == 'Sumava':
                 output.write(feature)
```